# Convert Firebase DocumentSnapshot data to a custom Scala (or Java) class

Tags: firebase, scala, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using Firebase for a private Scala project and I'm struggling to understand how I can manage Firebase responses if I want to avoid using HashMap.

This is the information that I'm trying to manage:

[image: This is the map that I'm trying to read]

These are the two Scala classes that I wrote with the idea to use them along with the `toObject` method:

```scala
class Doc() {
   @BeanProperty val map: util.HashMap[String, Value] = new util.HashMap[String, Value]()
}

class Value() {
    @BeanProperty val displayName: String                       = ""
    @BeanProperty val email: String                             = ""
    // Extra fields that I need to initialize in the Scala code
    @BeanProperty val totalLogins: Int                          = 0
    @BeanProperty val todoMap: util.HashMap[String, String]     = new util.HashMap[String, String]()
    @BeanProperty val todoList: util.ArrayList[String]          = new util.ArrayList[String]()
    @BeanProperty val totalChanges: Int                         = 0
    @BeanProperty val totalErrors: Int                          = 0
}
```

And this is snapshot listener implementation that I wrote:

```scala
docFirebase.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener[DocumentSnapshot]() {
  override def onEvent(snapshot: DocumentSnapshot, e: FirestoreException): Unit = {
    if (e != null) {
      println("[OnSnapshot] Listen failed: " + e)
      return
    }
    if (snapshot != null && snapshot.exists) {
      val doc = snapshot.toObject(classOf[Doc])

      // Here below I'll write the complex logic I need ...
    } else {
      println("[OnSnapshot] Current data: null")
    }
  }
})
```

Using that code I'm always getting an empty HashMap into the `doc` variable. Can someone helps me understand what I misunderstood about reading data from Firebase ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of your properties in the document are nested under an object called "abc".  That fact is not reflected in your code - you need to call out abc by name to get all the nested fields from it.  You probably don't want that nesting at all.  Just put all the fields (displayName, email, etc) as top-level fields in the document.

Comment: I make it nested because I can then easily delete elements. So there is no way to have a nested data structure and automatically create a HashMap[String, MyClass]? Isn't the HashMap[String, MyClass] reflecting what there is in the document on Firebase?

Comment: Nesting doesn't actually help with adding or deleting fields.  If you must have nesting, then you will need to deal with that in your code by reading the nested object field, then converting its contents to a class.